# Android Debugging by USB not working with WM6850 Tablet

Tags: java, android, usb, adb

I am developing an Android Application for a client and have run into a problem with the tablet that he wants it to run on. Long story short, I don't think I have the right USB drivers and can't find any applicable ones. I have tried to contact the manufacturer but no luck. The tablet is a WM6850 tablet running Android 2.2, I believe.

I have switched it to debugging mode and hit the switches that I needed to hit to allow foreign applications but I still can't see it under adb devices. If I switch it to use as a mass storage device, I can see it from Windows Explorer.

Does anyone know where I could find USB drivers for this device OR if there is something I have missed to get this device recognized?

Thanks for your help, if there is any more clarification needed I would be happy to provide.

-Iain

Comment: Did you check on their website? I think their support forum is best place for this question.

Comment: Their website usually has USB drives as well if you search for the device.

Comment: I didn't even get a manufacturer for this device. It is from somewhere in China.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a tablet before that seems to only allow for mass storage and not adb connections. One way you can check to see if it has any adb or usb debugging support is to usb it into a mac with the sdk. OSX and the android sdk work well enough together that no usb drivers are needed to communicate with it.

I know it doesn't help with your windows box situation, but may save you some trouble if it doesn't support adb connections out of the box.

Comment: Huh, that's a useful tip - would I need to install eclipse and the whole SDK/IDE on a mac in order to test this?

Comment: Just the SDK is sufficient, then you can start the terminal and run `adb devices` and see if it shows up there.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll try that tonight if I can get my hands on a Mac

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux as your OS you'll need to set the USB device rules in /etc/udev/rules.d

- Android [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)
- If you need help figuring out the [ID of your
  device](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1081648).

So perhaps in Windows you have some USB access permissions issues? That was my case on Linux, once I set the rules, then eclipse and ADT were happy bunnies.

Hope that helps.